# AWS opensearch search query are slow

Tags: opensearch

I'm using aws opensearch and it is can get extremely slow search

The default aws opensearch dashboard is useless for me, so I created a simple dashboard which works well most of the time, but then become extremely slow

The following image shows that i run queries, most of then are fast (less than a second) but then it get slow (1.6 min) and can also timeout

[image]

The first slow query is on Tue, 19 Jul 2022 14:38:27 GMT

When I look at cloud watch
it doesn't show any issue during this time
[image]

If I try to query from a different instance running the same code at the same time, it works well.

In the local log I print the stages of the connection and it seems that a request start, and then it just get stuck, i.e. I only see the `console.log(1)`

[image]

Therefor I assume the AWS service get stuck, but I don't understand why

NOTE:

- If I use the open search native dashboard, it is always very fast, even at time where the API is slow
- The query I run are for small data, max 100 lines

---

Edit:
I tired to increase instance size (was on minimum size) I assume this will solve the problem, will update in a couple of days
Edit: increase instance size didn't solved the problem

---

Comment: What is the difference to the other queries?

Comment: There is no difference on our end

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide more information about your instance sizes? Did you change anything in the default template of your indices?

Default is: 5 shards, 1 replica
This means:
All your date where splitted into 5 shards and duplicated (because of replica 1 means, having next to your index one replica).

Fix 1:
Do not scale vertically (larger instance size), scale horizontal -> second node. This will boost the performance by scaling.

Fix 2:
Adjust the number of shards to the number of nodes (if less then 3 nodes). E.g.

- 1 Node = 1 Shard
- 2 Nodes = 2 Shards
- 3 Nodes = 3 Shards
- 6 Nodes = 3 Shards

This logic will try to spread the shards in an optimum way to your nodes.
If you have replica 1, please note, that 1 shard will also produce 1 replica shard

I have some test opensearch services running with two nodes (1 CPU, 1GB RAM) and the performance is based on this settings "ok" without any issue (no replica, 2 shards for all indices)

Scaling up only one node to 2 CPU or 4 CPU won't bring you the performance you are expecting. For almost the same price, use smaller instance sizes but more of them.